# Android: bug with layout background (which shoudl not be white) on Android 4.2 and later

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view

I have a strange bug on Android 4.2 and later. I have a custom view (which is classical RelativeLayout, not a widget from an external library) which looks like this (normal look) on Android versions strictly lower than 4.2:

[image: The normal look of my view]

But it looks like this (white background = bug) on Android 4.2 and later :

[image: Buggy look]

Does anybody know what can be the reason ? I remember that I removed some holo.theme files from my project as I considered theme as useless, I don't see why it would be the reason but just to give complete information.

For info, I set the background directly in the xml like this:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/woodOfTopBarImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/topBarButtonsRelativeLayout"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/topBarButtonsRelativeLayout"
            android:src="@drawable/topbaripad3_2x"
             />
```

Thanks !!

Comment: How do you set the background?

Comment: This must be the issue with Themes that you are setting.

Comment: Henry: directly xml, see my edited question. androiduser: what do you mean ? ; I don't set any theme (as far as I know).

Comment: off topic - think about desing - "Don't use bottom tab bars" from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

Comment: What is the folder where the topbaripad3_2x lies?

Comment: ramaral: /res/drawable/topbaripad3_2x.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: it seems that on Android 4.2 and higher, the image resizing (with a scaling down) does not work properly if the image is too big (much larger and/or higher than the screen). I put a smaller source image and it works.